# Spring Kafka receive and forward another broker

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using `spring-kafka` to receive and send messages.

What i'm gonna do is read some messages from `X kafka broker` and do some enhancements and send to another `Y kafka broker`

Here is my beans and configurations.

```java
@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, AuditLog> forwarderKafkaProducerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
    configs.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9093");
    configs.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configs.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configs);
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, AuditLog> forwarderKafkaClient() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(forwarderKafkaProducerFactory());
}

@Bean
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, AuditLog>> kafkaListenerContainerFactoryV2() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, AuditLog> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
    configs.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
    configs.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    configs.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    configs.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "receiver-sender");
    configs.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    ConsumerFactory<String, AuditLog> consumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
            configs, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(AuditLog.class));
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
    return factory;
}
```

as you can see one broker runs in 9092 the other one runs in 9093

Receive/Forward logic is like that.

```java
@KafkaListener(topics = "audit_log", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactoryV2")
public void listen(@Payload AuditLog payload) {
    log.info("Audit log [{}]", payload);
    if (!payload.isForwarded()) {
        String key = "some-value";
        String system = String.join("/", key, payload.getSystem());
        payload.setSystem(system);
        payload.setForwarded(true);
        template.send("audit_log", key, payload);
    }
}
```

Template which is above the code snippet configurations are correct. I can confirm by looking `((DefaultKafkaProducerFactory)template.getProducerFactory()).getConfigurationProperties()`

In this configuration i can receive messages from 9092 but i can't send to 9093. Template always sending to 9092.

Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't make sense - edit the question show the INFO log showing the `ProducerConfig` (bootstrap.servers) property. I assume these brokers are NOT part of the same cluster (i.e. NOT using the same zookeeper) - if they are, the record will always be published to the broker that is the lead for the partition.

Comment: If you really wanted to consume and produce to different clusters, it's recommended that you use MirrorMaker for that

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell, as you assume my problem was incorrect kafka setup. I just posted answer now to help people who facing such a problem.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for your advice. i will look MirrorMaker project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Kafka setup was incorrect.
I use [wurstmeister/kafka](https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/kafka) on my current environment.

Docker compose file is like this.

```yaml
zookeeper:
  image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:3.4.6
kafka:
  image: wurstmeister/kafka:2.12-2.5.0
  ports:
    - "9092:9092"
  environment:
    KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "127.0.0.1"
  depends_on:
    - zookeeper
```

Then i just add second Kafka

```yaml
zookeeper2:
  image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:3.4.6
kafka2:
  image: wurstmeister/kafka:2.12-2.5.0
  ports:
    - "9093:9092"
  environment:
    KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper2:2181"
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "127.0.0.1"
  depends_on:
    - zookeeper2
```

But registry owners warns :) I saw this warning now while writing this answer.

> modify the KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME in docker-compose.yml to match your docker host IP (Note: Do not use localhost or 127.0.0.1 as the host ip if you want to run multiple brokers.)

I tried bitnami zookeeper/kafka

```yaml
version: "2"

services:
  zookeeper1:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/zookeeper:3.7
    ports:
      - "2001:2181"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka1:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/kafka:3
    ports:
      - "9201:9201"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper1:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CLIENT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=CLIENT://:9092,EXTERNAL://:9201
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=CLIENT://kafka1:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9201
      - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=CLIENT
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper1

  zookeeper2:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/zookeeper:3.7
    ports:
      - "2002:2181"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka2:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/kafka:3
    ports:
      - "9202:9202"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper2:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CLIENT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=CLIENT://:9092,EXTERNAL://:9202
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=CLIENT://kafka2:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9202
      - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=CLIENT
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper2
```

The code in question runs correctly with this setup.

Comment: You can have two Kafka clusters using the same Zookeeper, by the way, but changing the image didn't fix the problem as you could have set up the same properties in the wurstmeister one

Comment: Yes, you are right. I assumed the problem is wurstmeister itself so i change it.
I should edit the answer by using wurstmeister's image so people don't get it wrong.
Thanks for zookeeper trick :)